# Export data from NDSolve when they meet a certain condition

Tags: differential-equations, export

I need to export to a txt file the data from the following system of equations:

```
x'[t] == px[t],
y'[t] == py[t],
px'[t] == x[t]/(2*Sqrt[x[t]^2 + (1 - y[t])^2]),
py'[t] == -0.2 - (1 - y[t])/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + (1 - y[t])^2]
```

They can be reduced to two equations of x'' and y'', but the number of initial conditions is the same so that's arbitrary.

I successfully solved the system, for example, this way:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] == x[t]/(2*Sqrt[x[t]^2 + (1 - y[t])^2]), 
   y''[t] == -0.2 - (1 - y[t])/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + (1 - y[t])^2], 
   x[0] == x'[0] == Pi/3, y[0] == y'[0] == 0.5}, {x, y}, {t, -10, 
   1000}]
```

Now, how can I export the data from `NDSolve` when `y[t]==0` AND `py[t]>0` ? (in a 2-columm table txt file would be great)

Comment: Plotting `y[t]` shows that `y[t]==0` has two solutions on the interval you used. The roots are found using `FindRoot[y[t] /. sol, {t, -1}]
FindRoot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 4}]` which yields `{t -> -0.655304}` and `{t -> 3.66267}`, and by inspecting the plot, only `{t -> -0.655304}` satisfies `py[t]>0`. So your final data is just a single 2D point, `{x[t], y[t]} /. {t -> -0.655304} /. sol // Chop`, which yields `{0.444787, 0}`. I don't quite understand why you need to export this as a TXT file, since it's just a single point, so you could just type it in manually.

Comment: well this is an example only. the equation i really want  cross the 0 many times, so it would be better. thanks for the info tho

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if there is some kind of mistake (typo) the solution is to use `WhenEvent` with `Sow` and `Reap`:

```
{sol, {pts}} = 
  Reap@NDSolve[{x''[t] == x[t]/(2*Sqrt[x[t]^2 + (1 - y[t])^2]), 
     y''[t] == -0.2 - (1 - y[t])/Sqrt[x[t]^2 + (1 - y[t])^2], 
     x[0] == x'[0] == Pi/3, y[0] == y'[0] == 0.5, 
     WhenEvent[y[t] == 0 && y'[t] > 0, Sow[{t, x[t]}]]}, {x, y}, {t, -10, 1000}];
```

which gives

```
pts
(* {{-0.655304, 0.444787}} *)
```

ready to export.

Comment: i dont quite understand how to use properly those functions even afetr reading documentation, but that works. thanks sir!